# Cannot update with yum - Couldn't resolve host

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, linux-networking, yum

I have two issues on my bare KVM server, running CentOS 6.7 x86_64

1. Whenever I try yum update, I get a `PYCURL ERROR 6 - Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org`.

   Configuration in `/etc/resolv.conf` was with 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, I changed it to OpenDNS' IPs and still it didn't work.
   I even checked `ifcfg-eth0` and everything was fine. I also did `ifup eth0 up` and no results still. Rebooted my server many times.
2. I have VNC access to a server, and I want to access it through SSH. I have unblocked port 22 in iptables, modified the SSH config file to run on port 22 and Protocol 2, and even stopped iptables. I still can't login SSH.

Please guide me. I have searched everywhere and couldn't find the right answer.

Comment: does the virtual interface has link? Check it with ethtool eth0, you should see something like this:

Comment: VNC access? Is this light-out management access, some kind of console?

Comment: What about running dig  mirrorliat.centos.org ?? Is it definitely a DNS issue?

Answer (score 0):

(I have some questions to ask but i'm not commenting because of formatting. I'll update this answer after the eventual answers. Hope it's not a problem)

From your description it seems like a connectivity problem.

1) does the virtual interface has link? Check it with ethtool eth0, you should see something like this:

```
# ethtool eth0 | grep -i link 
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
    Link detected: yes
```

If that does not work check your virtual network configuration

2) If that check works, try resolving manually mirrorlist.centos.org:

```
# host mirrorlist.centos.org
mirrorlist.centos.org has address 84.22.180.89
mirrorlist.centos.org has address 88.150.173.218
mirrorlist.centos.org has address 108.61.16.227
mirrorlist.centos.org has IPv6 address 2a02:2498:1:3d:5054:ff:fed3:e91a
```